# Why did Kazuki Takahashi stop creating manga after Yu-Gi-Oh?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, kazuki-takahashi

Being a long time fan of Kazuki Takahashi's *Yu-Gi-Oh!* series, I tried to look into any manga that he may have produced after the completion of *Yu-Gi-Oh!: Millennium World*, but it seems like he just stopped writing manga after that.

Is there a reason why he stopped?

Comment: As of the date of this post, the only other work written by [Kazuki Takahashi](http://myanimelist.net/people/1913/Kazuki_Takahashi) is [*Drump*](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-10-17/kazuki-takahashi-draws-drump-1-shot-9-years-after-yu-gi-oh-end). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuki_Takahashi), he only played a supervisory role in newer volumes of *Yu-Gi-Oh!*. I cannot find any English statements detailing his inactivity. His [official website](http://studio-dice.com/) has been "under pause" for several years.

Comment: But... why did he stop?

Comment: It is just a wild guess, so I'll not post as an answer, but taking into account how the Yu-Gi-Oh! cardgame became popular, Takahashi doesn't need to work in anything different (not sure how much the TCG profits are divided between him, Konami etc., but anyway I suppose he got a good amount). I can't do that now, but it would be a good idea to see if there is some info about how much time Takahashi spends in the TCG development and/or company management, so maybe he is too occupied now with the RL card game to work on other manga.

Answer (score 1):

Mangaka tend to be somewhat reserved about their personal life. Takahashi has said of himself that he is great at postponing, leaving work until the last moment.

As already mentioned, he created a one-shot called *Drump* in 2013. He continues to oversee the development of the sequels of *Yu-Gi-Oh!* since he finished the original series in 2004. He has also actively participated in the development of the card game. To date, derivative manga and the card game are still being published, so he must consume part of his time in that.

In February 2015, a new adaptation of *Yu-Gi-Oh!* was run in Japan. This was due to the production of *Yu-Gi-Oh!: The Dark Side of Dimensions*, the most recent film of the franchise that celebrates the twentieth anniversary of the brand, and of which Takahashi is the author.

In short, I have no information for sure, but it seems that he is quite busy with his other activities to create something else.